# Find document files and copy them to another directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, find

This is a bit of a basic question but I'm trying to copy all .doc files I find in a directory and copy them to another directory.

I know each command:

```
find -name '*.doc' .
```

and:

```
cp filename location
```

How can I combine the two commands?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
find /path/to/search -name "*.doc" -exec cp {} /path/to/copy/to \;
```

If there are a lot of .doc files this is your best option to avoid hitting the [character limit](https://serverfault.com/questions/163371/linux-command-line-character-limit).

Comment: Or equivalently, but slightly faster: `find /path/to/search -name "*.doc" -exec cp -t /path/to/copy/to {} +`

Comment: @Gil, not equivalent, and not immune to the character limit.

Comment: @John: How are they not equivalent? As for the character limit, `find -exec … {} +` *is* immune to it (it operates like `xargs` without the quoting issues).

Comment: @gil take a closer look at the man pages, or, try it out with a few hundred thousand files in a deeply nested long path.

Comment: @John: About the limit: citing [POSIX](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html): “The size of any set of two or more pathnames shall be limited such that execution of the utility does not cause the system's {ARG_MAX} limit to be exceeded.” Citing find(1) on Debian lenny: “The command line is built in much the same way that xargs builds its command lines.”. And I just tested on Debian lenny, it did break up the file names into chunks correctly. About the equivalence: again, what difference do you see?

Comment: @Gil "POSIX" being the keyword there. It is not this robust in all versions of find. The non-equivalence comes from the amount of processes forked for total operation.

Comment: @John: What versions of `find` implement `-exec … {} +` incorrectly (as opposed to not at all, which is obviously the case for pre-POSIX:2001 implementations — but even though GNU utilities were quite late in implementing POSIX:2001, there aren't many older installations left now, especially on Ubuntu (6.06LTS had -exec … {} +))? (I'd like to know, since I try to write portable scripts.)

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility:

```
find /path/to/search -name \*.doc -print0 | xargs -0 cp --target-directory=/destination/path
```

This cuts down on the number of invocations of the copy command when compared to find -exec (should be noticeably faster if you have a huge number of files)

Comment: Slartibartfast's approach lets you use more sophisticated search/find filters with document indexing tools like `recollq 'keyword1 OR keyword2 AND ext:doc' | xargs cp --target-directory=~/Photos/of\ Hobson`

Answer (score 1):

On solaris you can use the following:

```
find /path/to/search -name "*.doc" -exec cp {} /destination/directory \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the files owned by user kelly, and copy them to a catalog: `/opt/dir`

```
# cd (into /path to copy files) e.g. cd /opt/
# mkdir dir (where you want to copy the files)
# find / -user kelly -exec cp -rfp {} /opt/dir/ \;
```

Answer (score 0):

To generalize you question from ".doc" to ".jpg" or other binary image files you'd need additional open source tools, like [tagim](http://github.com/hobsonlane.com/tagim) and [recoll](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/).

[tagim](http://github.com/hobsonlane.com/tagim) will tag your images with key words (or ratings) and then you can sort/filter them using [recoll](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/) and flow the list to `cp` using `xargs` to plug them together:

```
recollq 'ofJoe ext:jpg' | xargs cp --target-directory=~/Photos/ofJoe
```