# Find files in subdirectories and copy them to another directory with the same subdirectories?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, cp

This question is very similar [to this one](https://superuser.com/questions/208271/find-document-files-and-copy-them-to-another-directory) except that I want to maintain the file's original subdirectories.

For example if I had

```
/temp/a/a.txt
/temp/a/a.jpg
/temp/a/b.txt
/temp/b/c.txt
/temp/d/d.txt
/temp/d/d.jpg
/temp/d/e.txt
/temp/f.txt
```

I'd want to copy all the text files to /temp2 so that the directory structure would look like:

```
/temp2/a/a.txt
/temp2/a/a.jpg
/temp2/a/b.txt
/temp2/b/c.txt
/temp2/d/d.txt
/temp2/d/d.jpg
/temp2/d/e.txt
/temp2/f.txt
```

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replicate the whole directory structure, then simply do `cp -a /temp /temp2` if `/temp2` doesn't exist yet, or `cd /temp; cp -a . /temp2` if the target directory already exists. (`-a` is a Linux-specific options to `cp`; on other systems you can use `cp -Rp` for a recursive copy preserving permissions.)

If you want to copy only certain files based on their names, use [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync). It has sophisticated include-exclude rules; I wrote a [tutorial for these rules](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/rsync-failing-to-find-files/2503#2503) in response to a [question asking how to do this at Unix Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2161/885).

If you want to match files through other criteria such as the date, the simplest way is to combine `rsync` with zsh's pattern matching rules, as in [Marcel Stimberg's answer to the above-mentioned question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/rsync-failing-to-find-files/2169#2169).

Comment: Great, thanks for your help! Especially the links, they were just what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Without additional information, the best solution that I can suggest is:

```
cp -rp temp temp2
```