# Search for a text pattern in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I'm a linux newbie. I need to search for a string "teststring" in all *.java files coming under /home/user1/  (including subfolders). How can I do it in linux via shell command.

Comment: There have been several questions regarding regex searching files in subdirectories from the command-line

Comment: a quick search turned up this question: http://superuser.com/questions/208271/find-document-files-and-copy-them-to-another-directory not exactly what you are looking for, but instead of exec cp you could cat/grep whatever

Comment: I can list the file having the extension with find /home/user1 -name *.java How to use grep on that?

Comment: [find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l "some string"](https://superuser.com/questions/614526/finding-files-which-contain-a-certain-string-using-find-1-and-grep-1)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The easiest way is to use GNU grep's features:

```
grep -r --include '*.java' teststring /home/user1
```

If you're ever on another unix variant that doesn't have GNU grep, here's a portable way:

```
find /home/user1 -name '*.java' -exec grep teststring {} +
```

Comment: nice didn't know about this grep feature

Comment: If you're searching the current dir and all files it's `grep -r teststring .`

Answer (score 5):

using [ack](http://www.betterthangrep.com) you just type: `cd /home/user01 && ack --java teststring`

Comment: or `ack --java teststring /home/user01`

Answer (score 5):

For this **[ack](http://betterthangrep.com/)** aka **ack-grep** its the killer app in my mind ;)

You can `ack some_string /in/path_y` to find **some_string** in **path_y**
Or simpler `ack some_other_string` to find some_other_sting in current dir.

Answer (score 3):

Found it. Posting it as it might help someone.

```
find /home/user01 -name *.java | xargs grep "teststring"
```

Please correct if there is any better way.

Comment: Generally, you should use `-print0` and `-0` when piping `find` into `xargs` to work properly with files that may have spaces or newlines in their names: `find /home/user01 -name *.java -print0 | xargs -0 grep "teststring"`

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -irl teststring *java
```