# Finding files which contain a certain string using find (1) and grep (1)

Tags: bash, find

`find . -type f -print -exec cat {} \; | grep some string`

Command above doesn't print the file path.

I'm using: `Ubuntu, bash 4`.

Comment: Maybe it does not meet your expected results because of the grep filter.  What about this: `find . -type f -fprint /dev/stderr -exec cat {} \; | grep some string`

Comment: What is the goal you want to achieve? On output you are getting grepped strings from files, you want path of those files?

Comment: Yes I want to print the path of the files that contain the string 'some string'. @artistoex suggestion prints all file paths.

Comment: You may simply want to use `ack` to grep through all files under the current directory, possibly filtering on certain file types only.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

That's because you're feeding `grep` a stream of text which just happens to contain filenames. Since you provided no filenames as arguments to grep, it cannot be expected to deduce what file a matched line came from. Use `xargs`:

```
find . -type f -print | xargs grep "some string"
```

Since you have GNU find/xargs, this is a safer way for xargs to read filenames:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep "some string"
```

If you only want the filenames that have a matching line without showing the matching line:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l "some string"
```

Comment: How would I combine the above commands with search & replace? As in, grep then sed?

Comment: the find|grep pipeline outputs filenames, so: `sed '...' $(find ... | xargs grep -l ...)`

Comment: Why is the xargs necessary?  Why does it not work with just grep and no xargs?  What is the print0 doing?  Thanks

Comment: `find` outputs filenames. Without `xargs`, `grep` is just matching the pattern against the _filenames_ not the files' _contents_.

Comment: `-print0` prints the filenames using the NUL byte as the separator instead of newline. `-0` option for xargs uses the NUL byte as well. This is used because newline is a valid character for a filename, but NUL is not valid.

Answer (score 172):

I use:

```
grep "some string" . -R
```

and it works fast.

---

A more complex use case:

```
grep -HiRE "some string|other string"

# switches used:
# -H for file printing, 
# -i for case-insensitive, 
# -R for recursive search, 
# -E for regex
```

To display help on argument `i`:

```
grep --help | grep -- -i
```

Comment: And `-n` if you want line numbers.  +1 for simplified answer.

Comment: @ChadSkeeters exactly. Using the **find** does not give such solution.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, to be honest. The currently selected one details something else entirely.

Comment: Use `-e "search term"` if your searching for a string that looks like an argument and if you're getting the error `invalid context length argument`, e.g. `grep -Rn . -e "-C"`

Answer (score 23):

I often search for source code in complex folder structures and I find useful using:

```
cd /your/folder/
grep -rHino "your string"
```

With those parameters, *without using find*, I obtain the **file full path** and the **line number** that contains the **specified string**.

It is also easy to remember because it *BASH*es through your search like a **rHino** :)

I will show how this works with a quick example.

Let's display the content of a file using cat:

```
jeeves ~ # cat fw.stop
#!/bin/sh
echo "Stopping firewall and allowing everyone..."
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

And let's search recursively for all the files containing the string "iptables -P":

```
jeeves ~ # grep -rinHo "iptables -P"
fw.stop:9:iptables -P
fw.stop:10:iptables -P
fw.stop:11:iptables -P
```

As you can see in the output we have *filename:hit row:searched string*

Here's a more detailed description of the parameters used:

> **-r** For each directory operand, read and process all files in that directory, recursively. Follow symbolic links on the command line, but
>   skip symlinks that are encountered recursively. Note that if no file
>   operand is given, grep searches the working directory. This is the
>   same as the ‘--directories=recurse’ option.
>
> **-i** Ignore-case.
>
> **-n** Prefix each line of output with the 1-based line number within its input file. (-n is specified by POSIX.)
>
> **-H** Print the file name for each match. This is the default when there is more than one file to search.
>
> **-o** Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of matching lines, with each such part on a separate output line. Output lines use the same
>   delimiters as input, and delimiters are null bytes if -z (--null-data)
>   is also used (see Other Options).

Comment: Excellent.  Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: The only thing I would add to this is the `b` option which also shows the byte offset position, though `rHinob` is less catchy ;)

Comment: Maybe we could picture it as a suggestion... "Be rhino"! brHino :)

Answer (score 2):

I prefered

| find the file |make grep ont finding file   | show de full path of the file

find / -type f -exec grep 'some string' {} \; -exec echo {} \;

Answer (score 0):

[Silver Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) is a very fast and handy util to search for files and content.

To solve your problem the silver searcher command would look like this...

`ag 'some string' -l`

`-l` Only print filenames that contain matches (don't print the matching lines)