# Find number of files that contain certain String

Tags: bash, grep, find, string

I have a directory containing a vast amount of xml files. I would now like to find the number of files (and optionally the names of said files) that contain a certain string. XML tags do not really matter, each of the files can be seen as text files.

I have found a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/614526/finding-files-which-contain-a-certain-string-using-find-1-and-grep-1/614538?newreg=1384d0b57c484675a7f5939425e4c264), but this will output the whole file content. I am only interested in the filenames and the number of files that contain the given string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are commands run from inside the directory.

number of files:

```
grep -l text *.xml |wc -l
```

file names:

```
grep -l text *.xml
```