# Windows - how to copy searched/found files to another location?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I would like to write a batch file to search for files with a particular pattern in sub-directories and copy them to a particular directory. It seems easy [in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/208271/find-document-files-and-copy-them-to-another-directory) but how can I do that in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I may suggest how to do it with Far File Manager:

Navigate to target folder, press Alt+F7, enter filemask and pattern you're searching for, then (in results window) click Panel button, then (on the search panel) select all files with Gray+ and copy them with F5 to another Panel.

If you still insist on automation, using Powershell would be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I got the request completely, but may something like this help already?

```
   for /f "delims=#" %%i in ('dir /b /s *thepattern*') do ( 
     copy "%%i" C:\some_folder\
   )
```

/s searches in sub directories